# Should we have two copies of the same content or do a redirect?

Tags: google, redirects, duplicate-content, 302-redirect

We are a web app for icons and we've got 2 versions of our app:

- **Old one** with icon URLs like http://icons8.com/icons/#!/73/home
- **New one** with icon URLs like http://icons8.com/web-app/73/Home

Both apps are useful; the old one works well on mobile, while the new is not responsive yet.

**What should we do?**

1. Keep both copies
2. Do redirects from old to new
3. Much harder way — make new app responsive and replace the old app with a new one

Comment: You would have to redirect the `_escaped_fragment` version of your old URLs since a URL with a `#` can't be redirected from server side.

Comment: Yeah, we do that: http://icons8.com/icons/?_escaped_fragment_=/6931/rca

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, both apps are useful, you should keep them both.

However from what I see, the new one should be an evolution of the first, no? If so, you would be upgrading the first to the second, keeping only one.

I would upgrade the new one, make it responsive, look great and then keep just one, upgrading the first. For this you would keep the same URL so no redirected needed.

Comment: Exactly. The problem it will take about a month of development so I wanted to know how bad are the solutions 1 and 2.

Comment: as they are different sites you don't have problems like duplicate content, so keeping both shouldn't be a problem. About redirecting or not, is up to you and your business strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is 1 to 1 the same, then you can use the *origin* special header to let search engines know which page to view as the *correct* page.

So in your case BOTH pages would have this in their `<head>` block:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://icons8.com/web-app/73/Home"/>
```

That way is very SEO friendly. It means, though, that people will be sent to that new page (`web-app`) even if they have the old app. Yet again, if the content is the same, it wouldn't matter.

Now, if all of that content is not to be indexed anyway. That doesn't matter at all.

```
# robots.txt
Disallow: /icons
Disallow: /web-app
```